# Ticker object not iterable when using get_quote_yahoo to find the market cap of a number of stocks. TypeError: 'Ticker' object is not iterable'

Tags: python, yahoo, stock, yfinance

I am trying to find the market cap of a number of stocks that I have already gathered using get_tickers. Although it has already filtered by market cap I need to export it to an Excel Document for another project. I am basing it off code that I found on the internet but attempting to pull different data, the market cap instead of different data that was pulled using regular yfinance, however it gives me the error 'TypeError: 'Ticker' object is not iterable'.

```
tickers = gt.get_tickers_filtered(mktcap_min=500, mktcap_max=10000)

print("The amount of stocks chosen to observe: "+ str(len(tickers)))

Amount_of_API_Calls = 0 
Stock_Failure = 0
Stocks_Not_Imported = 0

i=0
while (i <len(tickers)) and (Amount_of_API_Calls < 1900):
    try:
        stock = tickers[i]
        temp = yf.Ticker(str(stock))
        market_cap = pdr.get_quote_yahoo(temp)['marketCap']
        Amount_of_API_Calls += 1
        Stock_Failure = 0
        i += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Yahoo Finance Backend Error, Attempting to Fix")
        if Stock_Failure > 3:
            i += 1
            Stocks_Not_Imported += 1
        Amount_of_API_Calls += 1
        Stock_Failure += 1
print("The amount of stocks we succesfully imported: " + str(i - Stocks_Not_Imported))

exportList = pd.DataFrame(tickers, market_cap, columns=['Ticker', 'Market Cap'])
print(exportList)
```